# Inkscape or Illustrator for this kind of work?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape

I want to make a similiar picture like this: https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/138443753/hd/ee481bcee17e5ee402d570ae3fa0d833.jpg

My question is now, should I use inkscape or Illustrator?
Will I need more time to do the picture with inkscape?
Would it be easier with Illustrator?

If I can do this with inkscape in nearly the same time like with Illustrator then I will stick to inkscape. We have free access to Illustrator at college, so the money is not the problem.

I'm a a game developer and want to make the art for the games myself at home. I don't have experience with either of the two softwares.

Answer (score 4):

Hum... From a technical point of view, you can achieve the same result in both programs. But how much time it will take depends on which program you are already familiar with.

But I feel, that you do not know either, so I am sorry but I'm answering with some questions.

Do you want to be an ilustrator or this is just a one time project and that's it?

If you want to do ilustrations, do you want to do them in your home, free time or depend on the college?

If you want to work at home, can your computer run inkscape?, Do you want to try ilustrator with the free trial period? (you can also try CorelDraw or Serif Draw plus)

If you want to do this "profesionally" you probably should stick with ilustrator, becouse it is a standard on the industry, so you need to interact with other people.

So, If you are starting to learn a program. Do that in Ilustrator.

Answer (score 4):

> should I use inkscape or Illustrator

Yes.

> Will I need more time to do the picture with inkscape? Would it be easier with Illustrator?

Depends on how familiar you are with both applications.

At the end of the day, they are two vector illustration tools. Software tools are a lot like woodworking tools. You can often use any variety of brands and models but each craftsman has their own personal preferences.